# TFS - add folder to label without including deleted items

Tags: eclipse, tfs, label

When I add folders to a label using TFS for Eclipse, it also includes the latest version of any deleted item, before it was deleted. It shows it with a ;Xvvv at the end, to indicate that it is not a currently existing version.

Is it possible to tell it not to do so - i.e. to ignore all deleted items when adding a folder to a label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by designed. *Labels* just let you take a **snapshot** of your files so that at a later date you can refer back to that snapshot.

> The decision to **add deleted items to labels was intentional**, and
>   helps with many scenarios where a Get operation is performed to return
>   to the state of the repository at the point in time which the items
>   were labeled. The use of merge with labels is also greatly improved
>   with deleted items in labels. One option that we can add here is to
>   improve how these labels are shown to users, and provide the option to
>   hide the deleted items from view. This is now a feature that we are
>   tracking on our product backlog.
>
> Thanks, Matt 
>   /Microsoft

Source Link: [Labels contain deleted files](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/646727/labels-contain-deleted-files)